# z3 and νz (z3opt): setting logic using the Python API

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I know that we can choose a logic like `AUFLIRA` to be used by Z3 or by νZ (or z3opt, the ***optimization*** branch of Z3) by writing

```
(set-logic AUFLIRA)
```

in the input `.smt2` file.

But what if we need to set this logic **using the Python API**? Which methods can we use to do this?

I checked some [documentation](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a2f0f1d8656f0f2f0adf46a1d37480274) and I noticed there is a `SolverFor(logicName)` in the `z3` module to create a Solver based on a given logic (e.g. by calling `SolverFor('AUFLIRA')`), but I have the following questions:

1. **What about νZ**? The `z3` module also has the `Optimize` object which works like the `Solver` object, but I didn't see any `OptimizeFor()` method to get an `Optimize` object for a given logic.
2. The `SolverFor()` method from the `z3` module **never raises exceptions**, even if I specify a **non-existing** logic by calling `SolverFor('abcd')`. The documentation says that if Z3 does not support the logic, then it will use the default settings, but **how can I know** if it is using the logic I provided (e.g. the `AUFLIRA` logic) or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nuZ does not expose customizable tactics/solvers because it makes very specialized use of solvers to find optimal values.

We should definitely address the fact that SolverFor('abc') does not create any warnings/exceptions. I am now seeing this problem in different user code examples and without warnings/exceptions it is likely that users will not be aware that their settings had no effect.

Comment: Many thanks Nikolaj for your clear answer. One final thing: I tried to use the (set-logic) command in nuZ directly in the SMT2 file (i.e. not via the Python API) and it works, it also generates different outputs depending on what logic is used, then you mean that custom tactics are not exposed only in the Python API?